# LI in my jquery effects my menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a jquery for an image slider  which can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/S4LGr/42/

And I have a classical horizontal menu with -ul- and -li- of course.

But this jquery, effects my menu and when I click on menu it doesnt work but it does the work of jquery, and changes the big div like I am clicking the litte thumbs which you can see in example.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Always put the relevant code/markup **in the question itself**, don't just link. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: I see T.J, sorry. I just thought it would be more practical and keep less place.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `$('li').click(fn)` you are literally saying in code, "hey jQuery, go find all `li` elements and whenever I click them, run `fn`."

You probably wanted to limit this to `li` elements which are children of `<div id="links">`, which is accomplished by using instead `$('#links li').click(fn)` instead.

You might also consider using instead `<ul id="links" class="horizontal_scroll_menu">` rather than the div-which-does-nothing that you have now. Try to cut down on needless divs on the Internet, please.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer, too. I tried your answer and it was good to know that option ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add more detail to the selector. `$("ul.horizontal_scroll_menu li")` should do the trick. See the implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/S4LGr/43/

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you, your help worked good for me. But I think you forgot to add a . before "ul.horizonta_scrol_menu li" in jquery part. Because I couldnt make it work at first but then with the help of a . I did it ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var container = $('#detail'),
bigimages =  container.find( "div");
bigimages.first().fadeIn("slow");
    $('.horizontal_scroll_menu li').each( function ( idx ) {
        $(this).click( function  ( e ) {
            bigimages.stop(true,true).hide().eq( idx).fadeIn("slow");
        })
    });​
```

try this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lee, I tried the simple solution of guys above without changing much my jquery. You know I am not so professional on it, but may try your one later too. Cheers